# Display array values as drop down list options in a wordpress form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to populate a *select* element in my HTML form with some array values.

**My code so far:**

```php
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-modal-label">
        <?php esc_html_e('State', 'motors'); ?>
      </div>
      <select name="state_alliancebusgroup" id="state" class="form-control">
        <option>
          <?php _e("Select","motors") ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach($states as $state): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $state ?>">
          <?php echo $state ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-modal-label">
        <?php esc_html_e('Industry Vertical', 'motors'); ?><span class="red">*</span></div>
      <select name="industry_vertical" id="industry_vertical" class="form-control">
        <option value="">
          <?php _e("Select","motors") ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category ?>">
          <?php echo $category ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Array**

```
$states = array(__("Alabama","motors"),
__("Alaska","motors"),
__("Arizona","motors"),
__("Arkansas","motors"),
__("California","motors"),
__("Colorado","motors"),
__("Connecticut","motors"),
__("Delaware","motors") );
```

How should I proceed to use the array values as dropdown list options?

Comment: And what do you have with your current code?

Comment: past it will display the drop down list

Comment: but now it cant be populated dropdown

Comment: can you tell me whats the problem in this code and how i solve it?

Comment: Check that `$states` has values right before `foreach`.

Comment: i cant get it what will you say

Comment: is your domain name `motors` isn't your `esc_html_e` trying to find a translation of the word `State` in a domain called `motors` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just populate your whole code in my function.php on in it code. and it worked for me. Please try this in your function.php and see if it worked there. if it worked there then you need to debug in your form page by stopping code at different chack points.

```
function populate_form(){

    $states = array(
    __("Alabama","motors"),
    __("Alaska","motors"),
    __("Arizona","motors"),
    __("Arkansas","motors"),
    __("California","motors"),
    __("Colorado","motors"),
    __("Connecticut","motors"),
    __("Delaware","motors")
     );
?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-modal-label">
        <?php esc_html_e('State', 'motors'); ?>
      </div>
      <select name="state_alliancebusgroup" id="state" class="form-control">
        <option>
          <?php _e("Select","motors") ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach($states as $state): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $state ?>">
          <?php echo $state ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-modal-label">
        <?php esc_html_e('Industry Vertical', 'motors'); ?><span class="red">*</span></div>
      <select name="industry_vertical" id="industry_vertical" class="form-control">
        <option value="">
          <?php _e("Select","motors") ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category ?>">
          <?php echo $category ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    die;
}
add_action('init','populate_form');
```

[image: The result i got by using this code in function.php]